# Identify movie or TV series episode with extraterrestrial giant insect-like creatures possessing people

Tags: story-identification

In particular I recall a scene where a man in a classroom, perhaps a professor, starts writing strange characters on the blackboard. At the same time he seems to be trembling profusely and then something like tentacles or antennas, presumably from an alien creature, emerge from his back.

It could have been a movie or a TV series from late 80s early 90s, but unfortunately I can't recall exactly when it was broadcasted.

Comment: I guess this is a completely different movie, I'm not sure about any details... "The Hidden" from 1987, starring Kyle MacLachlan. I has body snatching insect-like aliens but I think they come out of the mouth not the back mostly, and I remember scenes in police stations and a hospital, but no classroom. So this might be some other movie.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann , unfortunately that's not the one I'm looking for. It's amazing to see all the movies and tv series/episodes that were made with a similar premise during that time frame. I'm not sure but perhaps the one I'm looking for could have been a single occurrence with a one off appearance in an episode of the alien creature in one of those popular tv shows like Alien Nation and alike. I already watched the entire V tv series and The Highwayman but couldn't find it either.

Comment: This sounds like the two-part 1988 television movie, "Something is Out There." The plot is similar to the theatrical movie from the same era, "The Hidden". I also recall the blackboard scene. There was also a short-lived spin-off series.